# Secure way to transfer all of my Dropbox files to my Koofr account

Tags: encryption, cloud-computing, dropbox

I want to securely Transfer my Dropbox files to Koofr.

What's the best way to do this?

Here some additional information:

1. My Dropbox file are not encrypted.
2. Koofr can connect directly to Dropbox.

Do I need to encrypt my Dropbox files before any transfer takes place? Dropbox to my local machine to Koofr or Dropbox to Koofr?

Going toward best practices for securing cloud and transfers. I have been
recommended Cryptomator. I'd just encrypt sensitive files.

Syncing to local machine from cloud. Any security measures to take?

Comment: What do you want to be secure *from*? What bad thing do you not want to happen?

Comment: Good question. From my limited understanding if I drag and drop files they are unprotected during transit. I want my files to be secure during the transfer. I was wondering if I connect my Dropbox to Koofr and transfer would that be a protected environment? That's about it. I don't want my personal information stolen.

Comment: So, your question appears to be if the connection between the 2 uses TLS (HTTPS). And it would be very shocking indeed if Dropbox accepted unencrypted traffic.